# Add months to date with decimal place

Tags: python

I am using `dateutil` to add months to a specific date. How can I do that for months in decimal (eg. 1.5 months)?

My code is currently as below and it doesn't support decimal value for months.

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
dt = datetime(2018, 4, 9, 13, 37, 0)
new_dt = dt + relativedelta(months+=1.5)
```

Comment: “+1.5 months” is extremely vague even if you try to explain it verbally; there’s no way to provide a well defined result.

Comment: *datetime* does not support the notion of fractional months

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have typo

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
relativedelta(months+=1.5)
```

cause `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` after fixing that

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
relativedelta(months=+1.5)
```

there is `ValueError: Non-integer years and months are ambiguous and not currently supported.` (I checked that using python-dateutil 2.8.2 which is most recent version available at [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/#history)). Clearly python-dateutil do not support non-integer months. You would need to find way around this, if you are okay with finding day *around* 1.5 month later then consider using `relativedelta(days=+45)`